# The SELECT permission on table of user's own schema was denied

Tags: sql-server, vb6, database-administration

I have two applications on VB 6.0, AppOK and AppFailed. Both are connecting with a database on SQL Server with user AppUser and querying a table. AppOK succeeds and AppFailed fails with following error message.

> Run-time error '-2147217911 (80040e09)':
>
> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'xxxxx', database
>   'xxxxx', schema 'xxxxx'.

The table exists in AppUser's schema and when i grant the `SELECT` permission to the user explicitly it says

> Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner,
>   information_schema, sys, or yourself.

The AppFailed is able to query all other tables within the schema but fails on newly created 4 tables while AppOK can query all of them.

The Connection String of both the applications are exactly the same. Querying those 4 new tables via Management Studio while connected with AppUser works fine. The AppUser does not have any `DENY` permission.

I am unable to figure out the problem.

Comment: Just before querying your tables, add the code SELECT USER to see under which user your code is executing

Comment: @sepupic I used SQL Server Profiler and DatabaseName, HostName, LoginName, LoginSid and ServerName are exactly the same. Is it enough to ensure that both applications are using the same user?

Comment: No, it's not enough. Your code can use impersonation, EXECUTE AS USER. in this case the code is executed in the name of cited user, but profiler will still show you the same LOGIN

Comment: @sepupic I am simply opening the connection using a plain ConnectionString and then opening a RecordSet in VB 6.0. To my knowledge, there is no deliberate/coded impersonation or EXECUTE AS USER.

Comment: Do you use plain sql code or do you call any stored procedure?

Comment: @sepupic plain sql, SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME

Comment: But if you still enter the code SELECT USER just before this SELECT, does it return the expected user?

Comment: @sepupic Yes, it does return the same user name which i am connected with i.e. the user name in Connection String

Comment: Is this login a member of sysadmin group?

Comment: @sepupic For the given Catalog the user has these role memberships. db_datareader, db_ddladmin, db_owner, db_securityadmin, public

Comment: Is AppUser SQL Server login or Windows login (domain\AppUser)?

Comment: @sepupic It is SQL Server's login

Comment: If it's sql server login it cannot inherit permissions from windows groups. And if it's db_owner it doesn't need any explicit permission. So if it has no explicit deny, it's not db_owner at the moment of SELECT or it's a member of a custom role with DENY on this table. Please check if it's still db_owner immediately befor you issue the SELECT against your table: select is_member('db_owner')

Comment: @sepupic It returned 1

Comment: If your user is db_owner it has explicit DENY. Or itself or it's a member of another role with explicit DENY

Comment: @sepupic If this is the case then why is it working for AppOK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:(. The application was changing the Role of the user itself right after making connection (I didn't know about this), the role did not have rights for the newly created tables.

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly evident that there is some difference in the user role connecting from AppFailed.

Use SQL Profiler to trace warnings and errors from both application. The specific event you are looking for in SQL Profiler is described here: 
[Exception Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/exception-event-class)

Be certain to include columns related to user login and look for differences in activity from both the apps.

Here is some information on tracing errors using SQL Profiler: https://nimblegecko.com/how-to-trace-sql-server-database-errors-and-exceptions-with-sql-profiler/

Comment: If ConnectionString is exactly the same then how could user role be different !. I selected all events under Errors and Warnings, Only the ClientProcessID is different. DatabaseName, HostName, LoginName, LoginSid and ServerName are exactly the same. No error shown when executed the query from AppOK. Error which i have already posted shown when executed from AppFailed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1) dbaccess sysmaster 
2) grant select on syssqlstat to public;